# How to make a custom clickable shape with CSS to cover the exact needed area?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, css-shapes

I have to implement custom clickable area for my image in non standard shape (only for visible part of image). The shape is some part of the roof. I want to be able to do the click action only when I will hover over the shape.

Please see my example here in [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rt69rqjc/) and see what I am doing wrong and how can it be done in better way? I have a problem with selection of transform parameters and with locating the clickable area just under the shape. How to do it correctly and to have an exact cover for needed shape?

**Custom shape:**

[image]

**Example:**

```
<div class="image">
  <div class="image_roof_left">
    <a class="link_roof_left" href="http://creation.cal24.pl/opencart/index.php?route=product/product&amp;product_id=50"></a>
    <img src="http://creation.cal24.pl/opencart/image/data/poc/dach_l1.png">
  </div>
</div>

div.image_roof_left {
    border: 1px solid;
    left: 120px;
    top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    perspective: 150px;
    perspective-origin: 5% 0;
}
a.link_roof_left {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotateX(82deg) rotateY(-19deg) rotateZ(-6deg) skewX(-63deg) skewY(2deg);
}
```

Comment: How about just an image map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As **jme11** suggested, its better if you use an image map, as the sides of this shape are straight lines.

Open the image in an image editor to find out the coords.

**Snippet :**

```html
<img src="http://creation.cal24.pl/opencart/image/data/poc/dach_l1.png" usemap="#map">
<map name="map">
  <area shape="poly" coords="0,164,104,132,252,8,252,0,0,164" href="example.com" />
</map>
```

Comment: perfect, should be fine for me